# Auto refresh the Publishing Queue without modifying the Tridion product files

Tags: publishing, publishtransaction

Is there a way to auto-refresh Publishing Queue Tasks without modifying the core Tridon product files?
Once a user click "Show Tasks" within the Publishing Queue window, the auto-refresh should start.

Comment: The answers below give some decent pointers. But be aware that all of these will require significant development effort on your part. There is no existing solution that you can simply install. If you're looking for that, you may want to reach out to SDL or one of its partners to develop such a solution for you.

Comment: Note: @Alvin raised the auto-refresh of the Publishing Queue on the Tridion Ideas site a while back (login required): http://ideas.sdltridion.com/ideas/detail.asp?i=3576

Comment: If you have the A4T installed you can use this by just clicking install https://www.alchemywebstore.com/plugins/Real-Time-Publish-Queue

Answer (score 4):

Another recently available alternative would be to install [Alchemy](https://www.alchemywebstore.com/) onto your CMS system and then us the [Publish Queue Refresher](https://www.alchemywebstore.com/plugins/Publish-Queue-Refresher) plug-in.

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways of possibly doing this off the top of my head:

1. As Nickoli says, you could write a Custom GUI Extension for the CME interface.
2. You could script this using a [Bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) - This would also allow you to enter [the Tridion bookmarklet challenge!](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324/the-tridion-bookmarklet-challenge)
3. You could write your own Custom Page, using the Core Service, that watches the publishing queue and has a form of auto-refesh itself. (Obviously, not auto-updating the Publishing Queue window itself, but an option to consider.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way.  You would need to develop a custom GUI extension to do this.

Comment: The [ShowPublishTasks](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/source/browse/trunk/PowerTools.Editor/PowerTools/Client/ShowPublishTasks/ShowPublishTasks.js) PowerTool already presses the button for you when the window first loads. You could expand on this to press the button again at set intervals. If you do decide to add that feature, please share the code on the project so everyone can benefit :)

Comment: The PowerTools should be renamed to 'apps', just so that Peter can say "There's an app for that".

Answer (score 2):

Displaying the tasks in the publish queue is a pretty hefty database query, so auto-refreshing that might not be your best best.

Instead you could have a look at this tutorial by Will Price and Robert Curlette on how to send notifications about publish transactions state from (an event system on) the server to the browser: http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/signalr_messagecenter.aspx

[image: Message Center showing that publishing of 'abc' completed]

I used that approach in some past life to set up a Publish Queue Monitor page. Unfortunately I don't have the code anymore. But if you follow the steps in the article, you'll have most of the code that is necessary in place.

A Publish Queue Monitor would be slight simpler, because you could just make a custom page instead of a more full blown GUI extension, like what Will and Robert show.

Answer (score 0):

@Nickoli, We have the similar requirement.
What sort of GUI extension you are referring? And how can we integrate that to the existing publishingqueue popup?

Comment: Hi cherry, Welcome to the Tridion Stack Exchange site. I see you have written a note to Nickoli as an answer. This would have been better as a comment. Perhaps you can delete this question and add it as a comment instead. (Otherwise someone will undoubtedly clean it up, but it's nicer if you get to do it yourself.) Thanks